# PDFKit on Rails can't find my html footer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using PDFKit gem with Rails 4.2 (slim templates) and I'm having difficulty including an html template for my footer. I need styled text to appear at the end of every page.

When I put it in the head of my pdf template, as directed in the [PDFKit Wiki](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit/wiki/Configuration:-Global,-and-Per-Page), this line fails:

`meta name="pdfkit-footer_html" content="#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}/pdfs/footer.html"`

but this works fine, I just can't style it so it is not adequate for my needs:

`meta name="pdfkit-footer_right" content="Footer text goes here"`

My files:

`pdfs_controller.rb`

```
class PDFsController < ApplicationController
  def footer
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
get 'pdfs/footer', to: 'pdfs#footer'
```

`views/pdfs/footer.html.slim`

```
doctype html
| Footer text goes here
```

Both my baseurl/pdfs/footer and baseurl/pdfs/footer.html successfully give me "Footer text goes here".

The PDF works fine without the footer.

When I try to include it I get this error:

command failed (exitstatus=): /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf --quiet --page-size Letter --margin-top 0.75in --margin-right 0.75in --margin-bottom 0.75in --margin-left 0.75in --encoding UTF-8 --footer-html (mybaseurl)/pdfs/footer.html - -

and in the console

Error: Failed loading page (mybaseurl)/pdfs/footer.html?page=1&section=Search&sitepage=1&title=True&subsection=Mike Rasic&frompage=1&subsubsection=&isodate=2016-04-13&topage=4&doctitle=True&sitepages=4&webpage=-&time=3:10 PM&date=4/13/16 (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)

I know wkhtmltopdf needs exact URLs and I am trying to provide them.  I suspect it's getting messed up by the params that are getting tacked on at the end (in the console error message.)  But I don't know how to prevent that.  What am I doing wrong?